# How can I use a test set with python-weka-wrapper?

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, weka

I'm trying to integrate Weka into my Python code but can run only 10 fold cross-validation on the training set but I have to use a test set as well. Can anybody show me a simple example how to use a test set with `python-weka-wrapper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crosd-validation is only used for collecting statistics from internally built models. If you actually want to make predictions yourself, you need to build the classifier yourself using its `build_classifier` method and then either use `classify_instance` or `distribution_for_instance` to make a prediction per `Instance`.
See [this](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper-examples/blob/master/src/wekaexamples/classifiers/output_class_distribution.py) example.